# Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH - GoogleCloud

Tags: python, selenium

I just created a discord bot and its job is that scraping some data from web and do that help with selenium. On my own computer it works perfectly and i decided to upload it on any cloud server and make it online 7/24. So i found GoogleCloud for free and created an ubuntu VM. I installed required modules and just moved chromedriver to the path that test.py is located. When i type python test.py and execute, it works fine untill any function that has driver.chrome() statement works. Thanks for comments[ubuntu terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgoYZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Specify The executable_path Parameter Value When Initialize Firefox like belwo.*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: It is deprecated.

Comment: Updated the answer, according to comments, please share minimal code if still facing the issue